# What font have you found to work the best with OneNote's OCR feature?

Tags: font, onenote, ocr

I've been trying to do some OCR with Microsoft OneNote and am experimenting with what font seems to work the best. While some seem to be relatively good, I'm curious if anyone has any experience with OCR and has found a font to be nearly error proof? I found that Fixedsys causes errors at times, but not sure if something traditional like Courier or Helvetica would do better?

Comment: The OCR-A and OCR-B fonts spring to mind but I haven't tried them with OneNote.

Comment: Just wondering what your use scenario may be? If you control the contents, how could OCR be useful?

Comment: I scan documents and business cards all the time with OneNet and it seems quite proficient regardless of the font.

Answer (score 1):

Tahoma works really well with OneNote's OCR feature.